# Mais de um *Layout* na app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Como faço para instanciar uma nova tela, tenho o *Main.axml* e queria que quando clicasse no botão chamasse minha *Result.axml*. Gostaria de saber como faço isso no Xamarin em C#.
E se eu preciso de 2 *Activity's* uma para cada tela.

Também preciso passar valores da minha primeira atividade para a minha atividade (layout) secundaria.. como faço isso com c# (xamarin studio)?

Comment: PF gente me fala como faço para chamar uma nova atividade(tela) no xamarin

Answer (score 3):

Você deve criar um `Intent` e chamar `StartActivity` com este `Intent`. Para passar os parâmetros, use os `extras` que atuam como chave-valor para armazenar os parâmetros.

Perceba que cada axml está com uma `Activity` neste exemplo e seria a forma mais simples de alcançar o que você precisa. Teria como fazer tudo responder na mesma `Activity` mas creio que a solução ficaria mais complexa de entender.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace PrimeiraAtividade
{
    [Activity (Label = "PrimeiraAtividade", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LayoutUm);

            bttn.Click += delegate {
                var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(Result));
                activity2.PutExtra ("parametro1", edt.Text);
                StartActivity (ractivity2ess);
            };

        }

    }
}
```

Segunda Activity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace SegundaAtividade
{
    [Activity (Label = "SegundaAtividade")]         
    public class Result : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LayoutDois);

            TextView sm = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.meu_texto);

            sm.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("parametro2") ?? "Erro";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer isso

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(layoutDois));
    intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("Lista", Lista);
    StartActivity(intent);
```

Para mais duvidas o site da xamarim tem os primeiros passos
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides